# One Wordpress Install, Two Categories. Each Category Gets a Domain

Tags: categories, domain-mapping, customization

Ok here is a setup I am aiming for, hopefully someone knows how to get me there:

- One Wordpress Install on www.mainsite.com
- www.mainsite.com will be a landing page that points to two Category links: Work, Play
- Work Category defaults to domain www.worklife.com
- Play Category defaults to www.play.mainsite.com
- Any other Wordpress Pages will maintain www.mainsite.com as domain (ex. www.mainsite.com/contact)

Right now the old blog resides on worklife.com, so I am hoping to prevent the URLs of individual postings from changing (ex. www.worklife.com/2010/01/01/post) as I migrate the install to mainsite.com

For now, I have built the site, and all of the loops and pages are functioning correctly. The only thing left to do is get the domains to play nice so I can make the move.

All of my research keeps pointing me towards creating a network, but I'm hoping there is a way to keep it all running on a single install.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check out **[WordPress' Multisite feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)**? Simply put, it allows you to create a network of sites under different sub-directories, sub-domains, or domains. As with your case, each site in the network can work like a category.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible with a combination of website redirection and htaccess.

You can park (or addon) your domain names to their respective categories such as:
www.worklife.com goes to mainsite.com/work
play.mainsite.com goes to mainsite.com/play

Then, use htaccess to rewrite the URLs to show how you would like them to appear using [this as a guide.](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've been playing around with this but don't think I am 100% clear on what I can and can't do with this method.

If I rewrite worklife.com to mainsite.com/work, can I still make the URL display as worklife.com? When I have tried to set it up I think I have basically setup an endless loop.

Comment: This plugin may be useful for this task: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/