# 1 Wordpress installation with 2 pages: every page gets a separate domain

Tags: customization, domain-mapping

I have 1 WP installation with 2 subpages in it. Each of those 2 pages should get a separate domain:

Wordpress (domain1.com)

1. Home :: domain1.com
2. Subpage (id=8) :: domain2.com

Is this rather something done in .htaccess or is this possible in Wordpress itself?

I want to prevent setting up a multidomain network for this, as these are only 2 small pages.

Is there a working solution for this? I found this post which had a kind of similar question, but could not really follow it:
[One Wordpress Install, Two Categories. Each Category Gets a Domain](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22839/one-wordpress-install-two-categories-each-category-gets-a-domain)

Thanks!
Manuel

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You will need to install 2 WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have WordPress serve a different home page depending on the domain of the request. You'll need to do some setup:

- Make sure every domain you're planning on using is pointing to the server
- On the server, make sure the virtual host for each domain points to the WordPress directory. Alternatively you can just set the default web root and not have to worry about setting virtual hosts for each domain.

The first step is to make WordPress handle requests for any domain rather than just the domain it was installed on. You can do this by setting the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants in the `wp-config.php` file to use the host set in the request:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Next we have to determine what the homepage should be based on the request. We can do this by filtering the `page_on_front` option:

```
add_filter('pre_option_page_on_front', function($page_id) {
    switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
        case 'www.domain1.com' :
        case 'domain1.com' :
            return $page_id; // Default
        case 'www.domain2.com' :
        case 'domain2.com' :
            return 8; // Override
        default :
            exit; // We're not handling requests for this domain
    }
});
```

The above code can be added to your plugin or your theme's `functions.php` file. Make sure the filter returns a valid page ID. The post type must be `page` otherwise it will not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks! but still having troubles: the site is accessible with both domains, so domains are pointing to the same installation. but when insert the code into function.php, the page stays white (WP_HOME / WP_SITEURL seems to be ok). Currently the page is running in a subdomain (new.domain1.com / new.domain2.com), which I adapted in functions.php. Permalink are switched off. Any idea?

Comment: If the domains in the switch don't match the request domain then the script will exit. Try calling `var_dump` on `$_SERVER['HTTP_POST']` and comparing it to the domains in the switch. Also, make sure error reporting is on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly! I still had a copy/paste slash in the url...